# Evaluating norm of the operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to calculate norm of the operator $\varphi : l_{1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where

$$ \varphi( (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} ) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-4)^{-n} x_{2n}.$$

My attempt was as follow:

Let $||(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}||_1 \le 1$, than we have:

$\displaystyle |\varphi( (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} )| \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} | 4^{-n} x_{2n}| \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}|x_{n}| \le \frac{1}{2} || (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} ||_1 \le \frac{1}{2}$

So norm of this operator is at most $\frac{1}{2}$, but i can't find any $x_n$ such that in our inequality equality is obtaining.

Comment: Look at the line you wrote there.  Can you choose $x_n$'s so that all of those ${}\le$'s become ${}=$'s?  If you can, you are done.  If you can't it will show you how to get a better estimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inequality is not sharp enough to get an equality. Instead of using

$$\sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{4^n}|x_{2n}| \le \sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} |x_n| \le \frac{1}{2} \| (x_n)_n\|$$

you may use (using the same arguments in reverse order)

$$\sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{4^n}|x_{2n}| \le \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} |x_{2n}| \le \frac{1}{4} \| (x_n)_n\|$$

So the norm of the operator is at most $\frac{1}{4}$. Now to get an equality, you have to chose $(x_n)_n$ such that

$$\sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{4^n}|x_{2n}| = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} |x_{2n}|$$

and

$$\sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} |x_{2n}| = \sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} |x_{n}|$$

I'll leave you with this...